# How can I stack multiple (all) columns in a pandas.DataFrame directly on top of one another, in a single column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have been trying to figure out all day how to stack 24 columns of 100 rows into a single column. I read this in as a pandas DataFrame from a .xlsx file:

`df = pd.read_excel('some_groups.xlsx', index_col=[0]`

I want the columns to stack directly on top of each other in one column, without altering anything. I have tried looking into melt, stack, and so forth, but my brain is just not getting how to accomplish this.

I have provided an example below of what I am trying to accomplish. PS I am very new to programming, so simple explanations with good examples would be much appreciated. Thank you so much for any help!

starting DataFrame 3 columns A B and C with 4 rows below them:

```
A B C  
1 5 9  

2 6 10  

3 7 11  

4 8 12
```

The result I am wanting is to have a single column (pandas.Series?) with all of the rows stacked on top of one another, in the same order they originally were. :

```
A  
1  
2  
3  
4  
B  
5  
6  
7  
8  
C  
9  
10  
11  
12
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please format your dataframe properly. Take a look at [`how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: I think you need `df.melt()['value']`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Shubham Sharma. I looked more into df.melt()['value'] as you suggested and that got me to my next step.  I greatly appreciate the advice.  I ended up using this in my specific instance:
`df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Boise'])`